# Caesar Cipher code only Ciphers one letter not entire string

Tags: python, python-3.x, input, caesar-cipher

So I'm in the middle of making a simple Caesar cipher for practice and I can't get it to decipher entire strings, just individual letters.

`symbol_add` is the function in question.

Here's the code:

```
import re

alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"

def cleanIt(clean):
    global alphabet
    s = re.sub('[^a-z]+', '?', str(clean))
    return s

def symbol_add(symbol, key):
    encryptedMsg = ""
    for x in symbol:
        position = alphabet.find(x)
        newPosition = (position + key) % 26
        newLetter = alphabet[nyPosisjon]

    encryptedMsg += nyBokstav
    return encryptedMsg

def cipher(data,key):
    text = ""
    if data in alphabet:
        text += symbol_add(symbol=data,key=key)
        return text

def main():
    try:
        msg = (input("Write the message you would like to encrypt\n"))
        key = int(input("which key would you like to use?\n"))
        cleanIt(clean=msg)
        print(cipher(data=msg, key=key))
    except ValueError:
        print("Write a number!")

main()
```

I'm sure the solution is pretty simple, still learning.

Any help in how to solve this will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: your various functions seem confused about what they're operating on.  you need to make each function consistently process entire messages or individual characters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import re

alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"

def cleanIt(clean):
    global alphabet
    s = re.sub('[^a-z]+', '?', str(clean))
    return s

def symbol_add(symbol, key):
    position = alphabet.find(symbol)
    newPosition = (position + key) % 26
    newLetter = alphabet[newPosition]
    return newLetter

def cipher(data,key):
    text = ""
    for letter in data:
        if letter in alphabet:
            text += symbol_add(symbol=letter,key=key)
    return text

def main():
    try:
        msg = (input("Write the message you would like to encrypt\n"))
        key = int(input("which key would you like to use?\n"))
        # Note: you need to assign msg to be equal to cleanIt(clean=msg). 
        #       Just calling cleanIt(clean=msg) won't work, as strings 
        #       are immutable in Python
        msg = cleanIt(clean=msg)
        print(cipher(data=msg, key=key))
    except ValueError:
        print("Write a number!")

main()
```

The main changes are:

- The `for loop` was moved from `symbol_add` to `cipher`, so that `symbol_add` gets called for each character
- In `main()`: `cleanIt(clean=msg)` -> `msg = cleanIt(clean=msg)`; the reason for this is that strings are immutable in Python, meaning that you need to reassign the variable `msg` to essentially point to the new string.

Output of this code:

```
Write the message you would like to encrypt
test
which key would you like to use?
1
uftu
```

Also, try to stick to a single naming convention; you have a function that follows `camelCase` (`cleanIt`) and another that follows `snake_case` (`symbol_add`). Try and name all functions in the same way. (The convention in Python is to use `snake_case` for functions)

Comment: Thank you! i am aware of the conventional naming, i was translating from another language to make it more understandable and brainfarted :)

Answer (score 1):

You can streamline your cipher method quite a bit if you fill a dictionary as lookup when entering the method. It contains the mapping based on the `key` provided and maps your input characters to to the cipher-character.

Its much faster to look up in a dict then to `.index()` into a string.

Using `dict.get(key[,default])` allows to provide the `'?'` for unknowns so you need no `import re` and no preprocessing.

Read about `dict.get()`: [Why dict.get(key) instead of dict[key]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11041405/why-dict-getkey-instead-of-dictkey)

Adding uppercase mapping to the chiffre is trivial as well based on the lower case ones:

```
alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"

def cipher(data, key):
    # in case you change alphabet
    la = len(alphabet)

    # get the default lookup 
    chiffre = { c:alphabet[(i+key)%la] for i,c in enumerate(alphabet) }

    # create lookup for upper cases as well
    chiffre.update( { c.upper():n.upper() for c,n in chiffre.items() } )

    # supply ? for all unknowns, use the knowns where possible and return as string
    return ''.join( (chiffre.get(c,"?") for c in data) )

def main():
    try:
        msg = (input("Write the message you would like to encrypt\n"))
        key = int(input("which key would you like to use?\n"))

        print(cipher(data=msg, key=key))
    except ValueError:
        print("Write a number!")

main()
```

Output:

```
Write the message you would like to encrypt
Hello World
which key would you like to use?
1
Ifmmp?Xpsme
```